# Does change in package break existing clients using protobuf?

Tags: api, protocol-buffers

If I change,

```
syntax = "proto3";

package a.v0;

message HtmlStore{
    string html = 1;
}
```

to

```
syntax = "proto3";

package a;

message HtmlStore{
    string html = 1;
}
```

I have a python API which returns protobuf. There are existing clients consuming the API. I want to change protobuf definition of certain elements and I want to know if it will break the existing clients?

Answer (score 18):

Note: if you're using **JSON** encoding: all bets are off.

If you're using **binary** encoding, the `package` isn't *usually* part of the wire format - **unless** you've made use of the [`google.protobuf.Any`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any) feature.

So assuming you haven't used `Any`: changing the `package` will be completely invisible in terms of what is sent, and nobody will be impacted.

However! If they receive an updated version of the .proto and run the code-gen as part of their build, then their previously working code may cease to compile - requiring them to remove the `.v0` from code that references those types.

The only things that are sent on the wire are the field-numbers (1 in the case of `html`), the wire-type (length-prefixed in the case of `html` - so: wire-type 2) and the actual values. You can also safely rename `HtmlStore` and `html` (under the same conditions re `Any` etc).

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by JSON encoding in protobuf? I thought protobuf is always binary.

Comment: @Vikas nope, the Google libs include a JSON API too. It is very opinionated - you couldn't use it to parse ad-hoc JSON. Frankly I don't see the point of it: if you want JSON, use a good JSON library. If you're talking about protobuf you probably want perf as your primary driver, so you'd use the binary API.

Comment: What about changing the name of the Service? But not the methods/request/response.

Comment: @AlexandreMiziara for gRPC? the service name is part of the routing, so yes: that would be bad